# Vue JS: Is it safe to access state right after setting it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2

So my question is somewhat related to how state works in ***React*** i.e it gets updated `asynchronously`. So if we tried to access some state like the following -

```
this.setState({someState});
console.log('Value:',this.state.someState);
```

Then the value that will be logged will not be the value that we had just set. So if someone wanted to access the updated value. Then they would need to pass a `callback` to the `setState` function. Something like the following -

```
this.setState({someState}, () => console.log('Value:',this.state.someState));
```

My question is, in Vue JS, if I try to access the state right after setting it, the right value (i.e the updated value) gets logged. So is it safe to do so? I know we can define watchers in order to perform side effects on state changes. I'm just interested in knowing if the below code is safe to use. I'm also aware that state changes are not rendered right away, and they get updated asynchronously. I just want to know if we can access it, just like in the case of logging it right after setting it to a new value.

```
this.someState = 'new value'
console.log('Value:', this.someState) //This will log 'new value'
```

Comment: Yes, it's safe. Vue (assuming you're talking about v2) uses a proxy to wrap `data` properties. Assigning values is synchronous

Comment: @Phil Great, thanks! Could you please point me to a doc for the same? So that I can dive deeper on how this `proxy` works.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about Vue 2.

Comment: There's this one but it's pretty v3 centric ~ https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html#reactivity-in-depth

Comment: Here's the V2 equivalent ~ https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html. Only DOM updates are async. Programmatic updates happen immediately